# How to hide API keys when using React, firebase, and Github Action Deploy

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, github

I have a basic web application written in React that requires an API key to make requests. I want to be able to deploy my application on Firebase using Github Action Deploy (this I know how to do) and also be able to hide my API key. I have read many articles on hiding API keys in firebase but can't seem to figure out how to access them in react in a safe manner while also having the code base live on GitHub.

Comment: You can't. The React app runs in your users' browsers, so it can't directly use your key without exposing it to the public.

Comment: If you're asking about Firebase's configuration data (which contains a key that is unfortunately named `apiKey`) see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Is there a way to use dotenv and store the env variable in firebase?

Comment: Please read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Answer (score 4):

Well according to your comment, I think you want to store the API KEYS in the `.env` file and then you want to export them in your React app.

## For `.env.local` file

1. Create a `.env.local` file in your React source folder.

[image: React Folder]

2. Then put all of your API keys there, making sure that all of your API keys should start with `REACT_APP_` (Like this ).

```
REACT_APP_apiKey="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_authDomain="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_projectId="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_storageBucket="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_messagingSenderId="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_appId="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
REACT_APP_measurementId="<your api key here which you copied from firebase>"
```

3. And then you can get access to all these tokens in React by `process.env`. So your `firebase.jsx` file (or whatever you named) may look like this .

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_measurementId,
});

// NOTE THE USE OF `process.env.REACT_APP_...`
```

4. You can prevent `.env.local` from uploading to remote by adding it to the `.gitignore` file(which will be added by default to the `.gitignore` file provided by React).
   [image: .gitignore file]

Hope it helps !